# Stuck: How to link/connect two Azure Logic Apps together?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-cognitive-services

I am having some trouble trying to connect/link two Azure logic apps together.

Here is my scenario and how I am trying to use the Logic apps.

I have created a 1st Logic app :  that allows a user to upload a .mp4 media file into a folder on OneDrive, and the logic app checks to see if there is new file on that OneDrive folder. If there is new file, it will trigger the logic app and Index the video onto https://www.videoindexer.ai/.

2nd - Logic App : After the video is indexed to https://www.videoindexer.ai/ , I want the user to pick language(s) from the custom web page that I have created, for caption translation([here is the custom web page](https://jsfiddle.net/peterlearning/03dcxer7/1/)). Once the user choose the language(s) they click on "submit" and this will send the data(languages) to my 2nd logic app URL end-point, and trigger my second logic app and get the captions based on the user's selection of languages. Finally, it will then output those caption files on to a OneDrive folder.

Here is how I have created both the Logic apps:

**1st Logic APP:**

[image]
[image]
[image]

**2nd Logic APP:**

[image]
[image]
[image]

HTML:

```
<form id="language-form">
<h3>Please select the languages(s) for translating captions: </h3>
  <ul>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="en-US"> English</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="es-ES"> Spanish</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="ko-KR"> Korean</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="th-TH"> Thai</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="ja-JP"> Japanese</label></li>
  </ul>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function fetchForLanguages(languages) {
  console.info('starting fetch for', languages)
  return fetch("https://prod-00.westus2.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", { // this is my azure  provided endpoint
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      languages: languages
    })
  }).then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`Network response was not ok: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`);
    }
    return response.json()
  })
}


function handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  const data = new FormData(event.currentTarget)
  const languages = data.getAll('language')
  console.info('languages selected:', languages)
  fetchForLanguages(languages)
    .then((result) => console.log('got result:', result))
}

let form = document.getElementById('language-form')
form.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212479/discussion-on-question-by-peter-stuck-how-to-link-connect-two-azure-logic-apps).

Answer (score 0):

Here is workflow quite similar to yours with explanation:

[https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/logic-apps-flow-connectors-will-make-automating-video-indexer-simpler-than-ever/][1]

Here is python function to check for the file is ready before you send an email:

```
import requests

loc = '' # location 
acc_id = '' # account id
vi_subscription_key = '' # primary key

def get_access_token(loc, acc_id):

    headers = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': vi_subscription_key}
    params = {'allowEdit': 'true'}

    access_token_req = requests.get(
        f'https://api.videoindexer.ai/auth/{loc}/Accounts/{acc_id}/AccessToken',
        params=params,
        headers=headers)

    access_token = access_token_req.text[1:-1]

    return access_token


def is_video_proccessed(loc, acc_id, access_token, video_id, video_language='English'):        

    params = {'accessToken': access_token,
            'language': video_language }


    get_video_info_req = requests.get(
        f'https://api.videoindexer.ai/{loc}/Accounts/{acc_id}/Videos/{video_id}/Index',
        params=params)

    response = get_video_info_req.json()       

    if (response['state'] != "Uploaded") and (response['state'] != 'Processing'):
        print(f'Video {video_id} finished processing')
        return True
```

Hope this help.

Comment: I am Learning it as well. but my focus on using python. If you can integrate an Azure Function App that check for the stats of the file finished processing, then you send the email. I will add the function to the answer.

Comment: Before (send an email) step, you add Function App, and then add (control step) to check if the function app returned True, then you send an email.